# Why is my interaction collector not collecting? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am a beginner coder in javascript and especially discord.js
After wrapping my head around the discord.js guide, I still cannot get the collector to work.

```
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
  const filter = i => i.customId === '1' || i.customId === "2";
  const collectchannel = interaction.channel;
  const collector = collectchannel.createMessageComponentCollector( filter, { time: 10000 });

  collector.on('collect', i => {
    if (i.customId === '1') {
      client.commands.get('help').execute(interaction, 1, Discord);
    } else if (i.customId === '2') {
      client.commands.get('help').execute(interaction, 2, Discord);
    }
  });

  collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} interactions.`);
  });
});
```

When I press my button, the collect function doesn't do anything. I tried placing a `console.log("test")` but it doesn't fire. However, the `collector.on('end', collected => {` does in fact fire.
This may be because I'm not a good coder. If you can, please help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the interaction Ids are correct ? Try to place a `console.log(i.customId);` before both of your ifs inside the `collect` event

Comment: @Tenclea The collect event doesn't fire anything in the code, so I can't test that just yet. The log isn't being printed.

Comment: Can you try without the filter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `MessageComponentCollector` inside an event handler for the `interactionCreate` event, which, in this circumstance, is probably not what you want.

Here's what's happening:

1. You click the button
2. Your `eventCreate` handler fires, checks if it's a button being clicked and starts the MessageComponentCollector
3. The `MessageComponentCollector` waits for a button click, and doesn't fire yet because one has already happened (the one that fired your `interactionCreate` handler in the first place)
4. Whenever you click the button again, the collector fires, but the `interactionCreate` handler does too, and you go back to `#2`, starting another collector

---

What you probably want is to handle your button clicks without a collector:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    if (i.customId === '1') {
        client.commands.get('help').execute(interaction, 1, Discord);
    } else if (i.customId === '2') {
        client.commands.get('help').execute(interaction, 2, Discord);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you! I'm not smart, so I just used an unnecessary collector :D